# ios keyboard covers the input which is located in the bottom of the screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

ios keyboard covers the input which is located at the bottom of the screen. How can this trouble be solved?

here is the code.

```
 <Content style={styles.content}>

            <Form>
              <Item style={{borderBottomColor:'#42e8f4'}}>
                <Icon active name='mail' style={{color: '#42e8f4'}} />
                <Input placeholder='Email'placeholderTextColor= '#42e8f4' style={{color:'#0dc49d'}}/>
              </Item>
              <Item style={{ borderBottomColor:'#42e8f4'}}>
                <Icon active name='lock' style={{color: '#42e8f4'}} />
                <Input secureTextEntry={true} placeholder='Password'placeholderTextColor= '#42e8f4' style={{color:'#42e8f4'}}/>
              </Item>
            </Form>
            <ListItem style={{borderBottomWidth:0,borderTopWidth:0,borderBottomColor:'#42e8f4'}}>
              <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup")}>
                <Text style={{color:'#42e8f4'}}>Create Account</Text>
              </Button>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Forgetpass")}>
              <Text  style={{color:'#42e8f4'}}>Forget Password</Text>
            </Button>
            </ListItem>
            <Button full
              style={{backgroundColor:'#42e8f4'}}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Welcome")}>
              <Text style={{color: '#FFF'}}>Sign In</Text>
            </Button>
          </Content>

const styles = {
  content:{
    position:'absolute',
    bottom:10,
    left:0,
    right:0
  },
}
```

I am using Native-Base. How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 18):

Check the documentation for [React Native Keyboard Avoiding View](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview).

> It is a component to solve the common problem of views that need to
> move out of the way of the virtual keyboard. It can automatically
> adjust either its position or bottom padding based on the position of
> the keyboard.

Example from the [How to make your React Native app respond gracefully when the keyboard pops up](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580) article

```
 return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.container}
      behavior="padding"
    >
      <Image source={logo} style={styles.logo} />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Email"
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Username"
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Confirm Password"
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <View style={{ height: 60 }} />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
```

Comment: The problem is that above code which I wrote is inside the image, and image is like a container for the whole screen. where must I integrate above code? I added it after the image while the app is not rendering around 2 minutes and there is no any error message.

Comment: @NewTechLover I don't see any `Image` component in your question. You should wrap the main component that you want to be avoided by the keyboard. In your example this should be the `Content` component.

Comment: It solved for ios thanks. But when I use it android version which was great becomes affected from this solution. How can I specify this for only ios? I am using expo so there are not separate folders for each platform.

Comment: Take a look at [Platform Specific Code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html) on react-native docs. Please consider mark as answered if you thing the solution solved your main question.

Comment: I checked it but there is no any info how to ignore KeyboardAvoidingView for android

Comment: @NewTechLover have you found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this library [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) just make it as a container for your components

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution which works fine for ios and android both:

```
return (
   <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : ""}
          style={styles.container}>
          ........
          // Your input fields
          ........
         </KeyboardAvoidingView>
   </ScrollView>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
         flex: 1
      },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyboardavoidingview with padding hides the button for this use below code

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={"height"} 
style={{flex: 1}>
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  
      ........
    
</ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

1. Select info.plist in Project Navigator
2. Right-click on "Information Property List" at the top and select "Add Row"
3. Select "Launch screen interface file base name" from the droplist.
4. Set the type to "String".
5. I put "LaunchScreen" (without the quotes) for the value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Solution when you use ScrollView and it adds additional padding each time you click on Input:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : undefined} style={{flex: 1}>
   <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      
          ........
        
   </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```